# Move a folder to another in C#

Tags: c#, file-system

In C# I wrote a method to move a folder into another existing folder:

```
public void MoveFolder(string folderToMove, string destination)
{
    String destinationFolder = Path.Combine(
        destination, Path.GetFileName(folderToMove));

    Directory.Move(folderToMove, destinationFolder);
}
```

Usage:

```
MoveFolder(@"D:\myfolder\mysubfolder", @"C:\");
```

It works, but I am sure there is a more readable and shorter way to do that? In particular, I feel bad using `GetFileName`.

- No tricky things to worry about: The folders exist, and `destination` is not inside `folderToMove` nor the same.
- It must work on .NET 4.0 without additional libraries.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13260186/2224701

Answer (score 5):

This method is `public` but you don't do any validation about the passed in parameters which is a bad idea because your code is giving implementationdetails to a user of that method which he/she doesn't need to know. Assume `folderToMove == null`  then `PathCombine()` will throw an `ArgumentNullException` which is the correct exception, but this is telling a user that you are using `System.Path.Combine()` which he/she doesn't need to know.

You should better do the validation yourself and throw the expected exception.

---

Instead of `Path.GetFileName()` you should use a `DirectoryInfo` object and read its `Name` property which you could extract to a separate method to construct the destination foldername like so

```
    public void MoveFolder(string folderToMove, string destination)
    {
        if (folderToMove == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("folderToMove");
        }
        if (destination == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("destination");
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(folderToMove))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The parameter may not be empty", "folderToMove");
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(destination))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The parameter may not be empty", "destination");
        }

        String destinationFolder = CreateDestinationFolderName(folderToMove, destination);
        Directory.Move(folderToMove, destinationFolder);
    }
    private string CreateDestinationFolderName(string folderToMove, string destination)
    {
        var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folderToMove);

        return Path.Combine(destination, directoryInfo.Name);
    }
```

Comment: Another reason to choose the `DirectoryInfo` class over the `Path.GetFileName()` method is that if the source path ends with a backslash (\ ), the result of the method will be empty whereas the `Name` property of the `DirectoryInfo` class will still give the correct name of the folder.

Comment: Do you really always check strings first for null and then for emptiness? Somehow strange ;-)

Comment: @t3chb0t I do this just to throw different exceptions.